# Hybrid Mobile application: Phonegap/cordova vs. ReactNative Architectural differences?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, amazon-web-services, react-native

I have been developing hybrid mobile applications using cordova and HTML & JS, however I just came across React Native while I was planning to use [AWS Mobile SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/)

What are the architectural difference between cordova vs reactnative?

can some one who has worked on both, please share their findings.

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

React native is major upgrade over cordova.

React Native has no webview unlike cordova.
 It includes a Javascript interpreter (based on embedded V8 engine) that runs the logic of the application, using a Javascript interpreter per platform. 
  it uses just the JavaScript part of it.

Visual components (reusable UI elements) are rendered as a native UI. 
If a  component is used, the application will render a native Input, for each platform.

This means that UI layer is compiled from cross-platform html-like markup for each platform into the native code. 
 This results in higher performance of UI and much easier integration with native device features 
 (for example, drawing overlay over video stream from camera, etc).

High performance for UI’s is important enough that the React Native team has added a performance feature in the development wrapper, 
that measures UI performance (with FPS).

The “look” and “feel” of the mobile application will be more native like, when compared against a large hybrid application, just because the UI is native.

Both of them have AWS SDK

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-react-native

https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Amazon-AWS

Cons:

- Learning curve as it is different than Cordova. You need to learn
  native SDK to learn how to write markup.

Pros:

- React Native has much better performance than Cordova It’s
  cross-platform You don’t need to load your app on the device every
  single time you make some changes. It saves time and nerves React
  Native uses multiple cores simultaneously: JavaScript code runs on
  one core, app view — on the other It allows iterative testing Taps,
  gestures — all processed by platform (not by JavaScript as it is with
  Cordova)